# Webpack: Quasar is requiring unused knex driver dependencies

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, knex.js, quasar-framework

I´m running into a bug where, when using Quasar together with Knex, it is demanding a package for a driver that's not even in use:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                             8:34:02 AM
This dependency was not found:

* mssql/package.json in ../api/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mssql/index.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save mssql/package.json
```

This seems to be a problem with webpack, as per those other issues:

- https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1128
- https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1446#issuecomment-537715431
- https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/6553

Neither the technique of creating plugins to filter out the dependencies, nor the configuration of `externals` seems to work:

quasar.conf.js (please, take a look at the `extendWebpack` section):

```js
// Configuration for your app
// https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (ctx) {
  return {
    // Quasar looks for *.js files by default
    sourceFiles: {
      router: 'src/router/index.ts',
      store: 'src/store/index.ts'
    },
    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/boot-files
    boot: [
      'i18n'
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-css
    css: [
      'app.scss'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v4',
      // 'fontawesome-v5',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons' // optional, you are not bound to it
    ],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-framework
    framework: {
      config: {
        dark: 'auto'
      },
      iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      lang: 'en-us', // Quasar language pack

      // Possible values for "all":
      // * 'auto' - Auto-import needed Quasar components & directives
      //            (slightly higher compile time; next to minimum bundle size; most convenient)
      // * false  - Manually specify what to import
      //            (fastest compile time; minimum bundle size; most tedious)
      // * true   - Import everything from Quasar
      //            (not treeshaking Quasar; biggest bundle size; convenient)
      all: 'auto',

      components: [],
      directives: [],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: []
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/supporting-ie
    supportIE: false,

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-build
    build: {
      vueRouterMode: 'hash', // available values: 'hash', 'history'

      // showProgress: false,
      // gzip: true,
      // analyze: true,

      // Options below are automatically set depending on the env, set them if you want to override
      // preloadChunks: false,
      // extractCSS: false,

      // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/handling-webpack
      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            formatter: require('eslint').CLIEngine.getFormatter('stylish')
          }
        })

        // Contornando problema onde o webpack tenta, indevidamente, forçar o uso dos drivers não utilizados do Knex
        // Vide: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1446#issuecomment-537715431

        /*
        // force unused dialects to resolve to the only one we use
        // and for whom we have the dependencies installed
        cfg.plugins.push(new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/knex\/lib\/dialects/, /postgres\/index.js/));
        // pg optionally tries to require pg-native
        // replace it by a noop (real module from npm)
        cfg.plugins.push(new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/pg-native/, 'noop2'));
        */

        if (!cfg.externals) {
          cfg.externals = {};
        }
        Object.assign(cfg.externals, {
          // Possible drivers for knex - we'll ignore them
          'sqlite3': 'sqlite3',
          'mariasql': 'mariasql',
          'mssql': 'mssql',
          'mysql': 'mysql',
          'oracle': 'oracle',
          'strong-oracle': 'strong-oracle',
          'oracledb': 'oracledb',
          'pg': 'pg',
          'pg-query-stream': 'pg-query-stream'
        });
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
    devServer: {
      https: false,
      port: 8080,
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      pwa: false
    },

    // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest'
      workboxOptions: {}, // only for GenerateSW
      manifest: {
        name: 'Quasar App',
        short_name: 'Quasar App',
        description: 'A Quasar Framework app',
        display: 'standalone',
        orientation: 'portrait',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#027be3',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-128x128.png',
            sizes: '128x128',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'statics/icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
      id: 'org.cordova.quasar.app'
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },

    // Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {
        // https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#options

        // OS X / Mac App Store
        // appBundleId: '',
        // appCategoryType: '',
        // osxSign: '',
        // protocol: 'myapp://path',

        // Windows only
        // win32metadata: { ... }
      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'q-frontend'
      },

      // More info: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/node-integration
      nodeIntegration: true,

      extendWebpack (cfg) {
        // do something with Electron main process Webpack cfg
        // chainWebpack also available besides this extendWebpack
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Why do you bundle your node deps? they should remain in node_modules :]

Comment: I see... the frontend seems to be erroneously packaging up Knex, for some reason...